# No route matches [GET] error bluehost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-2.1

I know this is some basic stuff but i'm not sure why i'm getting this type of error.it's driving me nuts.we moved our site to bluehost from site5 ,i did all the config setting there but i'm getting  No route matches [GET] error.

```
link : http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/~fuegotic
```

When i call the link this message shows

[image]

app_config.yml

```
development: &local
    site_name: MY Site Name
    site_url: http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/~fuegotic
    app_url: http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/~fuegotic/appfolder/app/assets/images/
    js_url: http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/~fuegotic/appfolder/app/assets/javascripts/
    css_url: http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/~fuegotic/appfolder/app/assets/stylesheets/
    upload_url: http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/~fuegotic/appfolder/public/
    folder: appfolder

production:
  <<: *local

staging:
  <<: *local

test:
  <<: *local
```

routes.rb has following line

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

rails -v

```
Rails 3.2.13
```

ruby -v

```
ruby 2.1.4p265(2014-10-27 version 48166)[x86_64-linux]
```

rake routs has following route

```
root    /     home#index
```

Dose the non ASCII sign "~" in url is causing the problem?? I'm running out of ideas.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like the app is running on XXX.XX.XX.XX. Have you configured apache/nginx yourself?

Comment: No, our client gave it us the server details with pre installed gems, passenger other requirements ,and we are  just installing our site on it.
i thought the same because why it should look for "/~fuegotic" when i already have give that in config file as site_url.
how can i configure the apache/nginx to solve this.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

Comment: Thanks for the help guys it was the URL problem like i mention before. 
we changed back to regular URl instead of temp URl and and the issue is resolved for routs. And now there seems to be a problem with active admin but we are in touch with Blue Host Team they are trying to solve the issue.